# How to access the div class with particular h1 tag text name?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I need to get the information inside the div class of particular H1 class text.Below is the HTML code:

```html
html
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="SAyv5">WHO Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) situation reports</h1>
       <div> This content1 I need </div>
     <div>  This content2 I need </div>
       <div>  This content3 I need </div>
        <p>This is my first page.</p>
        <h1>A secondary header.</h2>
    <div>  This content4 I need </div>
        <p>Some more text.</p>
    </body>
```

Here I need only content of the div class which is under the H1 tab text "WHO Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) situation reports". Likewise there are multiple H1 tab but I need to access them only one H1 tab text. **I have to access them with this text "WHO Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) situation reports".**

Comment: Plz provide us with a url

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access them in css this is how i would go around it.

**html**

```
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="content1Container">
        <h1 class="SAyv5">WHO Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) situation reports</h1>
        <div> This content1 I need </div>
        <div>  This content2 I need </div>
        <div>  This content3 I need </div>
       </div>
       
       <div id="otherContentContainer">
         <p>This is my first page.</p>
         <h1>A secondary header.</h2>
         <div>This content4 I need</div>
         <p>Some more text.</p>
       </div>
       
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
#content1Container div{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
ht = """your html above, fixed"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(ht,'lxml')

targets = soup.find_all('h1',string="WHO Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) situation reports")
for target in targets:
    for t in target.fetchNextSiblings('div'):
        print(t.text)
```

This should output the text from all the `<div>` elements following the `<h1>` element with the required text.

Comment: Yes, this is correct but I need to fetch some particular div tags which has different class names like <div class = 'WqlSx' \div>. Like this there are many different class names. Which I want to fetch with the H1 tag string.

Comment: @RajGokul In your question, `<div>` tags have no classes. If you also want to select `<div>` s which only contain a specific class, please edit the question, add such `<div>` s and indicate which one are to be selected and which are not.